# Use VBA to disable Excel linked data type refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the Excel Stock linked data type in a spreadsheet where I use VBA to generate the list of tickers to get quotes for. I then convert them to linked data types using

```vb
.Sheets("Quotes").Range("B1:B" & Row).ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-AU"
```

It seems that by default, the quotes refresh automatically every 5 minutes, however for the purposes of my application this is undesirable. It seems I can disable this in Excel by using the "Data Types Refresh Pane" and setting the Refresh rate for "Stocks" to "Manually" as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-refresh-linked-data-types-44cd357f-4679-4c2e-bc65-1e3dcf94809f):

[image]

However as these spreadsheets are created and populated automatically by VBA this isn't very practical.

Is there a way to change this refresh setting programmatically via VBA?

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Certainly lots of googling failed to return a result...

Comment: I was looking  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.linkeddatatypestate here but it's read-only

Comment: Here https://office-watch.com/2022/excel-automatic-refresh-recalculation-tricks/ you can set the refresh for all, but not set the timing or disable it. "' Repeat every minute or change to whatever value you prefer.

   `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "AutoRefresh"`


' this is a simple example. There's no coded way to exit this function."

Comment: @Bradipo thanks for the info, that property might have been useful otherwise... as for the code on `office-watch.com`, that requires you setting refresh to "Manually" as well, otherwise you get automatic refreshes *as well* as the ones from that code.

Comment: I think you can copy + paste values on linked data types to "freeze" them. At least you can with the type returned by powerquery to stop it refreshing

Comment: @Greedo that's not a bad idea for a workaround.

Comment: @Greedo [something](https://sqlspreads.com/blog/excel-linked-data-types-an-introduction/) regarding your approach

Comment: and [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/09/06/the-m-behind-the-new-power-query-data-types-in-excel/) too, something that could be related.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Excel at hand to test so you'll have to experiment a bit.

Option 1 as mentioned in the comments is to copy + paste values to "freeze" the linked data type. I'm not sure this definitely works on linked data types, it does on the power query variety.

Option 2 is to read the linked data type into power query, expand it to make all the fields new columns, then collapse it using "Create Type". Again untested whether PQ can load a linked data type from the sheet. Then copy+paste values the result.

Option 3 will definitely work. Expand all the fields into the worksheet as new columns with a formula. Load all the fields into PQ and create a new record type from them as in option 2.

All 3 can be automated with VBA

Comment: I'm not accepting the answer as it is just a workaround, not an actual solution to the problem. But you've earned the bounty. thanks